# Hyperparameters for Reproducing the Results of IRGAN on MovieLens 1M

Tags: generative-adversarial-networks, hyper-parameters, recommender-system, collaborative-filtering

I am trying to reproduce results reported for IRGAN (information retrieval GAN) on the [MovieLens 1M](https://grouplens.org/datasets/movielens/1m/) dataset. The results I want to reproduce and their sources are listed in the table below.

| Model | Precision@5 | NDCG@5 | Source |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| IRGAN | 26.30% | 26.40% | [CFGAN](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/3269206.3271743) |
| IRGAN | 30.98% | 31.59% | [CoFiGAN](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0950705119305659) |
| IRGAN | 31.82% | 33.72% | [BiGAN](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/pdf/10.1137/1.9781611976236.10) |

While my implementation of IRGAN is able to reproduce the results on the [MovieLens 100k](https://grouplens.org/datasets/movielens/100k/) dataset, I am having problems discovering the hyperparameters for reproducing the results on the [MovieLens 1M](https://grouplens.org/datasets/movielens/1m/) dataset; currently [my IRGAN implementation](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1GidpegOTUyxIZawEJaQqNaZ01nCA93Zo?usp=sharing) is achieving a precision@5 score of 21.7%.
Unfortunately, the authors of the aforementioned papers do not share the hyperparameters used for training their version of IRGAN.

Thus, I want to ask if there is a repository with the used hyperparameters?
Furthermore, I would be most grateful if you could provide me information on how to contact the authors?